# Blocking web sites with Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-firewall

Is it possible to use Windows Firewall to block specific web sites for all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to achieve that using the Advanced Settings of the firewall. But you will need to know all the ip addresses of the remote servers.

See [this](http://garethhwilson.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/adding-icmp-exception-to-windows-2008-firewall/) example which talks about ICMP but you can do the same for any traffic. The Scope tab would be of interest because that's where you would define the remote ip of the web server(s).

Comment: The key thing being, "the IP addresses of the remote servers." The Windows firewall can't block "facebook.com", it can block 69.63.181.12 (etc) though.

Comment: Does the "local IP Addresses" list apply to the local intranet? Is there any way to specify no local IP addresses?

Comment: The "local IP addresses" refers to the ip address(es) of the machine's network card(s) or 127.0.0.1. But if you wanted to block access to this machine from the local network, then you would need to specify the ip addresses for the local machines/network in the remote ip as well. As far as the firewall is concerned, unless it resides on the local machine, then it is considered remote. More information would help answer the second question. Is this server the middleman between clients and websites? What role does it play?

Comment: This is on a workstation.

Comment: OK. When you say "no local ip addresses", do you mean allowed or denied? No matter which one, you can create a second firewall rule where you specify the local subnet to be allowed or denied.

Answer (score 0):

Its probly better to block in the router or if you want it on a machine only do a redirect in the hosts file.  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)